# How to extract maven proxy in code

Tags: java, maven, proxy, jersey, maven-plugin

I'm writing maven plugin that send POST HTTP requests using Jersey client.
My problem is that I have to go thru my organization proxy.

I can configure the proxy myself using:

`System.setProperty ("http.proxyHost", PROXY_HOST_NAME);
System.setProperty ("http.proxyPort", PROXY_PORT);`

But, I want to have more elegant solution - use the proxy I've configured in maven settings.xml 
The question is: How can I get the proxy info using Java code? (I tried to search MavenSession for a hint, but could not find it).

Thanks! 
Shay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use an [attribute like this](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugin/PluginParameterExpressionEvaluator.html) in your mojo:

```java
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${settings}", readonly = true, required = true )
private Settings settings;
```

This will give you access to all things within the settings file.